# UITextView right to left Unicode \u202B not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, unicode, uitextview

I am essentially making a teleprompter app and I need a UITextView to display right to left for EVERY line.

```
NSString *textString = @"Hello There\nMy name is Mark";
textView.text = [@"\u202B" stringByAppendingString: textString];
```

This is not working.  I need this to read

"          erehT olleH"
"      kraM si eman yM"

I understand that I also need fonts that are upside down etc.. I need to get this part fixed first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation `\u202b` denotes the Unicode character U+202B is RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING, which does not affect the writing direction of characters with strong directionality, such as Latin letters.

The character U+202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE (`\u202e`) forces right-to-left writing direction, overriding the inherent directionality of characters. To end its effect, use the U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING character:

```
'\u202eHello There\nMy name is Mark \u202c'
```

This has little to do with fonts. The rendering engine is supposed to handle some characters like “(” using mirrored symbols, e.g. so that “(foo)” gets rendered as “(oof)” and not “)oof(” in right-to-left writing. But generally, no mirroring is involved; letters remain the same, they just run right to left.

If you actually want to have text mirrored, you need something completely different (a transformation).

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic for reversing the string... I hope this helps you... Just append this string in your `textView.text`

```
 NSString *sampleString = @"Hello this is sample \n Hello there";
    NSMutableString *reverseString = [NSMutableString string];
    NSInteger index = [sampleString length];
    while (index > 0) 
    {
        index--;
        NSRange subStrRange = NSMakeRange(index, 1);
        [reverseString appendString:[sampleString substringWithRange:subStrRange]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", reverseString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Amit.  That code would work if I had strings with only a few words.  Since this will be a teleprompter app, it would need to be for long speeches and wouldn't reverse it for every line break.

Comment: did u try this ? it works for more number of lines too. It just worked for me.